# Composer does not cache packages referenced by commit

Tags: composer-php

My project automated deployment relies on Composer to install all dependencies.
Every time I deploy, deployment scripts asks for a fresh install, but the composer.lock is always the same, no dependency changes between deploys.

Librairies referenced with a version number (`"twig/twig": "1.12.*"`) loads from cache. But thoses with a branch/commit reference (`"dompdf/dompdf" : "dev-master#424c235"`) always triggers a git clone to GitHub.

As for the others libraries, theses versions didn't changed, but aren't loaded from cache.

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies from lock file

- Installing phenx/php-font-lib (0.2.1)
Loading from cache

- Installing dompdf/dompdf (dev-master 424c235)
Cloning 424c235

- Installing endroid/qrcode (dev-master 4eb83c9)
Cloning 4eb83c9

- Installing j4mie/idiorm (v1.3.0)
Loading from cache

- Installing j4mie/paris (v1.3.0)
Loading from cache

- Installing jamesiarmes/php-ews (master edbcb65)
Cloning edbcb65

- Installing symfony/process (v2.3.1)
Loading from cache

- Installing kriswallsmith/assetic (dev-master 0a55a9b)
Cloning 0a55a9b

- Installing kriswallsmith/buzz (v0.10)
Loading from cache

- Installing psr/log (1.0.0)
Loading from cache

- Installing monolog/monolog (1.5.0)
Loading from cache

- Installing mtdowling/cron-expression (v1.0.1)
Loading from cache

- Installing respect/validation (0.4.4)
Loading from cache

- Installing ruudk/twitter-oauth (dev-master a4c0094)
Cloning a4c0094

- Installing slim/slim (2.2.0)
Loading from cache

- Installing slim/extras (2.0.1)
Loading from cache

- Installing symfony/console (v2.2.2)
Loading from cache

- Installing tedivm/jshrink (v0.5.1)
Loading from cache

- Installing twig/twig (v1.12.3)
Loading from cache

- Installing zendframework/zend-stdlib (2.1.5)
Loading from cache

- Installing zendframework/zend-authentication (2.1.5)
Loading from cache

- Installing zendframework/zend-permissions-acl (2.1.5)
Loading from cache

- Installing zendframework/zend-session (2.1.5)
Loading from cache
```

### TL; DR;

How to make Composer fetch from the local cache the dependencies referenced by a commit ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't clone from Github, download ZIPs instead. The flag `--prefer-dist` will trigger this when you update. Without this, there is no cache entry for that package, there is only the cloned repo in the `vendor` folder which pulls in any changes and then checks out the required commit id.

Comment: But what if I want to cache a repo/dev/commit?

Comment: You'd create a ZIP from it, like `--prefer-dist` does download, wouldn't you.